# How can I mix itemize and tabular environments?

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I have the following list:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item És associativa:$\qquad(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$
    \item És commutativa:$\qquad x+y=y+x$
    \item Té element neutre:$\qquad\exists 0\in\K : 0+x=x+0=x$
    \item Té element invers:$\qquad\forall x\in\K\;\exists(-x)\in\K : x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$
\end{itemize}
```

But I want to align that like

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    És associativa:&$\quad(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$\\
    És commutativa:&$\quad x+y=y+x$\\
    Té element neutre:&$\quad\exists 0\in\K : 0+x=x+0=x$\\
    Té element invers:&$\quad\forall x\in\K\;\exists(-x)\in\K : x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$\\
\end{tabular}
```

How can I "mix" them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a *minor* enhancement to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75723/16550) solution.

Using [the `array` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) you can define a new column type `L` which automatically inserts the bullet at the start of the column in which it is used:

[image]

### Notes:

- This could also be done with [the `collcell`  package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell). This commented out in the code below, but that would only make sense if there was further processing you wanted to do with the entries in the first column.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % add packages you need here ...

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\labelitemi~~}l<{}}

%% Don't need above two lines if want to use `collcell` pacakage
%\usepackage{collcell} 
%\newcommand*{\AddBullet}[1]{\labelitemi~#1}%
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\collectcell\AddBullet}{l}<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand*{\K}{\mathbf{K}}%  Not sure what \K is supposed to be

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{L l}
    És associativa:    & $\quad(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$\\
    És commutativa:    & $\quad x+y=y+x$\\
    Té element neutre: & $\quad\exists 0\in\K : 0+x=x+0=x$\\
    Té element invers: & $\quad\forall x\in\K\;\exists(-x)\in\K : x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But in my case the list is inside another list, so I have used `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\labelitemii~~}l<{}}`. Is there a way to make it recognize automatically the level of the list?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but that would be a excellent separate question to ask here as it may be useful to know in situations other than this specific case.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this (`\textbullet` inserts the bullet, and you have to mark the new row with a `&`. To be more flexible you can use `\labelitemi` instead of `\textbullet` as Juri said in his comment):

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75717/how-can-i-mix-itemize-and-tabular-environments#comment161963_75717
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % add packages you need here ...

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
    \labelitemi & És associativa:&$\quad(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$\\
    \labelitemi & És commutativa:&$\quad x+y=y+x$\\
    \labelitemi & Té element neutre:&$\quad\exists 0\in\K : 0+x=x+0=x$\\
    \labelitemi & Té element invers:&$\quad\forall x\in\K\;\exists(-x)\in\K : x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put `\def\curlabelitem{\csname\csname @itemitem\endcsname\endcsname}` in your preamble, you can then use `\curlabelitem` and it will point out to the correct thing at every place.

Comment: @tohecz It throws errors. Must I include any package?

Comment: Well, you might want to use `\\[\itemsep]` instead of `\\ ` to get the proper spacing.

Comment: @Oriol oh sorry, things might be a bit more complicated. I forgot you're _not_ in the list. It should be: `\makeatletter
\def\curlabelitem{\begingroup\advance\@itemdepth\@ne\csname labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth\endcsname\endgroup}
\makeatother`

Comment: @tohecz Thanks, your last code works. But which is the list I'm not in? And how can I use `\\[\itemsep]`, and what does it do?

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement for intermixing the two environments if you manage some of the box widths yourself. The following MWE shows an environment `myitemize` - based on `itemize`, that breaks across the page boundary and sets the width of an item (`\myitemlen`) if it's set at the beginning of the environment. Otherwise, it takes the natural width of each specified item.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\newlength{\myitemlen}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{%
  \olditem\ifdim\myitemlen>0pt
      \makebox[\myitemlen][l]{#1}%
    \else
      #1%
    \fi}
\newenvironment{myitemize}
  {% \begin{myitemize}
   \begin{itemize}\let\olditem\item\let\item\myitem}
  {\end{itemize}}% \end{myitemize}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbf{K}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
  \item{És associativa:} $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$
  \item{És commutativa:} $x+y=y+x$
  \item{Té element neutre:} $\exists 0\in\K : 0+x=x+0=x$
  \item{Té element invers:} $\forall x\in\K\;\exists(-x)\in\K : x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$
\end{myitemize}

\begin{myitemize}
  \settowidth{\myitemlen}{Té element neutre:\qquad}
  \item{És associativa:} $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$
  \item{És commutativa:} $x+y=y+x$
  \item{Té element neutre:} $\exists 0\in\K : 0+x=x+0=x$
  \item{Té element invers:} $\forall x\in\K\;\exists(-x)\in\K : x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I change the texts later maybe the widest one will be another item, istead of "Té elemetn neutre:"

Comment: @Oriol: Exactly. And you can change that again. It would be possible to modify the environment into something different (like `myitemize`) so that you specify the text that is the widest every time you use it. [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) can also be employed here. Note that a `tabular` will not break across the page boundary, while a regular `itemize` will.

Comment: @Oriol: I've updated my answer to be a little more user-friendly. :)

Answer (score 0):

One more simple solution

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % add packages you need here ...

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand*{\K}{\mathbf{K}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \parbox{3.5cm}{És associativa:}    \parbox{6cm}{$\quad(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$}
  \item \parbox{3.5cm}{És commutativa:}    \parbox{6cm}{$\quad x+y=y+x$}
  \item \parbox{3.5cm}{Té element neutre:} \parbox{6cm}{$\quad\exists 0\in\K : 0+x=x+0=x$}
  \item \parbox{3.5cm}{Té element invers:} \parbox{7.5cm}{$\quad\forall x\in\K\;\exists(-x)\in\K : x+(-x)=(-x)+x=0$}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]